# Dynamically fetching only related values instead of all attribute values in dropdown from GeoJSON in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, geojson, dropdownlist

I have a vector layer in GeoServer which basically has `14 line/fields/polyline attributes`

I want the list of only those stations in the 2nd dropdown of end station which are actually related

Like `5 out of 14 lines` in the shapefile `(highlighted with yellow)` are `originating/starting` from New Delhi.

[image]

```
FID     Start_station         End_Station
306     New Delhi             Ambala
307     New Delhi             Rohtak
1230    New Delhi             Saharanpur
1231    New Delhi             Hapur
1232    New Delhi             Aligarh
```

I am fetching the attributes from column named `FROM_` in the shapefile in the dropdown as

```
var select_from = $('#from_station');
var from_station_Array = new Array();
Railway_Layer.getSource().on('addfeature', function (e) {
  const name = e.feature.get('FROM_');
  var value_station_from = String(name);
  if (jQuery.inArray(value_station_from, from_station_Array) == -1) {
    select_from.append(
      "<option class='ddindent'>" + value_station_from + '</option>'
    );
    from_station_Array.push(value_station_from);
  }
  // console.log('FROM_ station names are ', name);
});
```

[image]

& I am fetching the attributes from column named `TO` in the shapefile in the dropdown as

```
var select_to = $('#to_station');
var to_station_Array = new Array();
Railway_Layer.getSource().on('addfeature', function (e) {
  const name = e.feature.get('TO');
  var value_station_to = String(name);
  if (jQuery.inArray(value_station_to, to_station_Array) == -1) {
    select_to.append(
      "<option class='ddindent'>" + value_station_to + '</option>'
    );
    to_station_Array.push(value_station_to);
  }

  // console.log('TO_ station names are ', name);
});
```

I want if I Select New Delhi from 1st dropdown, then only these 5 stations *viz:* `Ambala, Rohtak, Saharanpur, Hapur, Aligarh` whose originating point is `New Delhi` should appear in the 2nd dropdown, instead of whole list.

Currently, the whole list appears here in the 2nd dropdown.

In case if I select `New Delhi` from 1st dropdown, and any value, to whom `New Delhi` is not related i.e. not an originating point then the query does not run.

e.g: if I select `New Delhi` from 1st dropdown & `Kurukshetra` from 2nd, it will not work, as `New Delhi` in the shapefile does not have `Kurukshetra`as its related attribute

[image]

[Manually assigning them values and then Mapping with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570904/use-jquery-to-change-a-second-select-list-based-on-the-first-select-list-option) is not feasible as there are lot of stations, which keep on changing/updating.

so basically, How to map values from a column based on another column in the shapefile?

[Refer to this URL for working Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/station-name-add-station-name-in-table-forked-u1rx3)

Comment: Should selection of `To Station` be allowed if `From Station` is not selected yet?

Comment: It may be ```either ways```/```both ways```, if we select ```From Station``` first then, only ```related```/```relevant``` stations should appear in ```To Station``` dropdown, or if we select ```To Station``` first, then only related stations should appear in ```From station``` dropdown. that way we don't need to block selection of ```To Station```

Comment: This will get things very complicated. If you first select `To Station`, you then limit what is available in `From Station`. But if you then select from `From Station` you will have to limit what is available in `To Station` and so on. Might be confusing for end user.

Comment: Okay, @TomazicM, Then the first option that you suggested is good to go.. i.e. Selection of ```To Station``` should not be allowed until some value from ```From Station``` is not selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you have to do to make it work:

- Set variable `featureNames` with all the travel relations as global, so it will be available for filtering `To Station` when `From Station` is selected.
- Initially build only `From Station` options, `To Station` field should be disabled.
- When `From Station` is selected, clear any previous `To Station` drop down options and then loop through `featureNames` and build drop down options for `To Station` from those end stations which have origin in selected `From Station`.

That's how relevant part of the code could then look:

```
function addStationOption(value_station, station_Array, select) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(value_station, station_Array) == -1) {
    select.append(
      "<option class='ddindent'>" + value_station + '</option>'
    );
    station_Array.push(value_station);
  }
}

var select_from = $('#from_station');
var from_station_Array = new Array();
var select_to = $('#to_station');
var to_station_Array = new Array();
var featureNames = [];

Railway_Layer.getSource().on('addfeature', function (e) {
  var feature, name, value_station, FID, start_station, end_station;
  
  feature = e.feature;
  name = feature.get('FROM_');
  value_station = String(name);
  addStationOption(value_station, from_station_Array, select_from);

  FID = feature.get('FID_IMD');
  start_station = feature.get('FROM_');
  end_station = feature.get('TO');
  featureNames.push({
    FID: FID,
    start_station: start_station,
    end_station: end_station
  });
});

Railway_Layer.getSource().on('change', function (ev) {
  if (Railway_Layer.getSource().getState() !== 'ready') return;

  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    fixedHeader: {
      header: true,
      footer: true
    },
    data: featureNames,
    columns: [
      { data: 'FID' },
      { data: 'start_station' },
      { data: 'end_station' }
    ],
    scrollY: 300,
    paging: false
  });
});

select_to.prop('disabled', true);
select_from.change(function() {
  var selection = this.value;
  to_station_Array = [];
  select_to.empty();
  select_to.append('<option value="">To Station</option>');
  select_to.prop('disabled', (selection.length == 0));
  
  if (selection.length == 0) return;
  
  featureNames.forEach(function(feature) {
    if (feature.start_station == selection) {
      addStationOption(feature.end_station, to_station_Array, select_to);
    }
  });
});

select_to.change(function() {
  var selection = this.value;
  if (selection.length == 0)
    console.log('No end station selection');
  else {
    console.log('End station selected: ', selection);
  }
});
```

And one remark: this is not really a GIS related question, but pure HTML/JS one, so please in the future post this kind of questions on StackOverflow site.

Comment: Here I put because features were being called from GeoJson, but Sure, I will keep that in mind in future. Thanks for your time.